# How often is "best of a bad bunch" used in the Anglosphere?

Tags: idioms

I found this expression at the COBUILD Advanced Leraner's Dictionary which for the most part is a British English dictionary, and I wonder whether it is commonly used by English speakers all around the world as if it were a very common phrase in the Anglosphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an American, I have never heard someone say this before, so I wouldn't say it is common. As Michael Harvey points out, some people clearly use it in the US (at least in formal writing). Despite this, the equivalent "best of the worst" is very common here.

Answer (score 2):

Not 'exclusively' British

> Animal Kingdom and Shackleford are little more than the best of a bad
> bunch of 3-year-old thoroughbreds.
> New York Times, June 11 2011
>
> Houston Rockets: 1976-95 home The problem with the Rockets' history of
> jerseys is finding a kit that doesn't look like a promotional tool for
> a certain red-and-yellow-themed fast-food restaurant. The old-school,
> Hakeem-era home jerseys are the best of a bad bunch.
> Fox News Sports
> (USA) Dec 13 2016